# Two Different Size Queries is not display record parallel Or Front .I want to display record Paralle in Php with Oracle

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, array-merge

Here is code given a varaiable of contract_n is coming from json or jquery

```
$contract_n = $_POST["contract_n"]; 
if(!empty($contract_n)){
 $date1 = '01-JAN-2000';
 $date2 = '31-DEC-2099';
}else{
$date1 = $_POST["date1"];
$date2 = $_POST["date2"];
}
$date1 = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($date1));
$date2 = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($date2));  


$date1 = strtoupper(substr($date1,0));
$date2 = strtoupper(substr($date2,0));

$main_q = "
SELECT   CONTRACT#,1 sr,CONTRACTDATE,SALEMANID,SALEMANNAME,CUSTOMERID,CUSTOMERNAME, SHIP_DATE,CONSTRUCTIONID,DESCRIPTION,LOOMABRV,WEAVENAME,
SUM(SHIP_MTR) SHIP_MTR,
MAINPRODUCTNAME,  SHIP_QTY ,WEB_Y_N
FROM

V_SALECONTRACT_MTR
WHERE  CONTRACTDATE BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
AND CONTRACT# = NVL('$contract_n',CONTRACT#)
GROUP BY CONTRACT#,CONTRACTDATE,SALEMANID,SALEMANNAME,CUSTOMERID,CUSTOMERNAME, SHIP_DATE,CONSTRUCTIONID,DESCRIPTION,LOOMABRV,WEAVENAME,
MAINPRODUCTNAME,ship_QTY,WEB_Y_N
";
```

Here is I take sub total

```
 $query = "

$main_q

UNION ALL
SELECT  CONTRACT#,2 SR, NULL CONTRACTDATE,NULL SALEMANID,NULL SALEMANNAME,NULL CUSTOMERID,NULL CUSTOMERNAME, SHIP_DATE SHIP_DATE,NULL CONSTRUCTIONID, NULL 
DESCRIPTION,NULL LOOMABRV,NULL WEAVENAME, SUM(SHIP_MTR) SHIP_MTR,
NULL MAINPRODUCTNAME,  SUM(SHIP_QTY) SHIP_QTY , NULL WEB_Y_N FROM ($main_q)
GROUP BY CONTRACT#, SHIP_DATE 
UNION ALL
SELECT   CONTRACT#,3 SR,NULL CONTRACTDATE,NULL SALEMANID,NULL SALEMANNAME,NULL CUSTOMERID,NULL CUSTOMERNAME,NULL SHIP_DATE,NULL CONSTRUCTIONID, NULL 
DESCRIPTION,NULL LOOMABRV,NULL WEAVENAME, SUM(SHIP_MTR) SHIP_MTR,
NULL MAINPRODUCTNAME, SUM(SHIP_QTY) SHIP_QTY ,  NULL WEB_Y_N
FROM ($main_q)
GROUP BY CONTRACT# 
ORDER BY CONTRACT# ,SHIP_DATE,SR
";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid);
```

2nd Query

```
 $q_2 = "
SELECT A.CONTRACT#,1 SR2 ,C.REQDATE,DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION2,WEAVENAME WEAVENAME2,l.loomabrv loomabrv2,A.DEMAND#,C.QUANTITY


FROM 
DEMANDMST A,DEMANDDTL1 B,DEMANDDTL2 C,v_construction v,weave w,loom l , CONTRACTMST T
WHERE A.DEMAND#=B.DEMAND# AND
    B.DEMAND#=C.DEMAND# AND
    B.ROW_ID=C.ROW_ID AND 
    b.SCONSTRUCTIONID=v.CONSTRUCTIONID and 
    b.WEAVEID=w.WEAVEID and
    b.LOOMID=l.LOOMID
    and a.contract#= t.contract#
    and T.CONTRACTDATE BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'
   AND a.contract# = NVL('$contract_n',A.CONTRACT#)
--Group by Reqdate and contract#
UNION ALL 
SELECT A.CONTRACT# ,2 SR2 ,C.REQDATE,NULL DESCRIPTION,NULL WEAVENAME,NULL loomabrv,NULL DEMAND#,SUM(C.QUANTITY) QUANTITY


FROM 
DEMANDMST A,DEMANDDTL1 B,DEMANDDTL2 C,v_construction v,weave w,loom l , CONTRACTMST T
WHERE A.DEMAND#=B.DEMAND# AND
    B.DEMAND#=C.DEMAND# AND
    B.ROW_ID=C.ROW_ID AND 
    b.SCONSTRUCTIONID=v.CONSTRUCTIONID and 
    b.WEAVEID=w.WEAVEID and
    b.LOOMID=l.LOOMID
    AND a.contract# = NVL('$contract_n',A.CONTRACT#)
   and a.contract#= t.contract#
    and T.CONTRACTDATE BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'
    GROUP BY A.CONTRACT# , C.REQDATE 
    --Group By Contract Date
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT A.CONTRACT# ,3 SR2 ,NULL REQDATE,NULL DESCRIPTION,NULL WEAVENAME,NULL loomabrv,NULL DEMAND#,SUM(C.QUANTITY) QUANTITY


FROM 
DEMANDMST A,DEMANDDTL1 B,DEMANDDTL2 C,v_construction v,weave w,loom l , CONTRACTMST T
WHERE A.DEMAND#=B.DEMAND# AND
    B.DEMAND#=C.DEMAND# AND
    B.ROW_ID=C.ROW_ID AND 
    b.SCONSTRUCTIONID=v.CONSTRUCTIONID and 
    b.WEAVEID=w.WEAVEID and
    b.LOOMID=l.LOOMID
    AND a.contract# = NVL('$contract_n',A.CONTRACT#)
   and a.contract#= t.contract#
    and T.CONTRACTDATE BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'
    GROUP BY A.CONTRACT# 
    ORDER BY REQDATE 
 ";
 $stid2 = oci_parse($conn,  $q_2);
oci_execute($stid2);
?>
<span id="status"></span>
<br>
<table id="contract_req_mtr" style="padding-top: 20px;">
      <thead>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
       
       <th>Sales </br> Contarct #</th>
       <th>Dated</th>
       <th>Manager</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
         
          <th>Ship Date</th>
           <th>Quality</th>
           <th>Weave</th>
           <th>Loom</th>
         <!--  <th>Process</th> -->
           <th>Mtrs</th>
           <th>Product</th>
            <!--   <th>Consumption</th>-->
           <th style="border-right: 3px solid lightblue;">Qty</th>
           <th>Required Date</th>
           <th>Quality</th>
           <th>Weave</th>
           <th>Loom</th>
           <th>Demand No</th>
           <th>Qty</th>
      
    </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php


        $prev_contract = NUll;
        $prev_shipdate = NUll;
        $prev_reqDate = NULL;
        $t_shipMtr = 0;
        $t_shipQty = 0;
        $t_Qty = 0;
        $row_1 = []; 
        while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) 
       {
        $row_1[] = $row;
       }
       $row_2 = [];
        while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_ASSOC)) 
       {
        $row_2[] = $row;
       }
```

Merge Two array Here

```
//
$results = array(); // define an array that will contain all the rows

    //iterate on the first array assuming its name is $array1
foreach($row_1 as $val) {
            //add the current line named $val to the resulting array
    $results[] = $val;
}
    //iterate on the first array assuming its name is $array1
foreach($row_2 as $val) {
            //add the current line named $val to the resulting array
    $results[] = $val;
}

//$results = [...$row_1 ,...$row_2];
```

Sorting of two combine array below

```
usort($results, function($a, $b) {
 
    return [$b['CONTRACT#'] ?? '', $b['SHIP_DATE'] ?? '' ,$a['SR'] ?? '', $b['REQDATE'] ?? '' , $b['DESCRIPTION2'] ?? '']
           <=>
           [$a['CONTRACT#'] ?? '', $a['SHIP_DATE'] ?? '' , $b['SR'] ?? '', $a['REQDATE'] ?? '' , $a['DESCRIPTION2'] ?? ''];
});
```

Display Result from array_merge varaiable $result

```
       foreach($results as $row){
 
            $g_contract = $row["CONTRACT#"] ?? '';
            $sr = $row["SR"] ?? '' ;
            $sr2 = $row["SR2"] ?? '';
            if($sr == 1){
                if(!empty($row["SHIP_MTR"])){
                $t_shipMtr += $row["SHIP_MTR"];
        }
             if(!empty($row["SHIP_QTY"])){
                $t_shipQty += $row["SHIP_QTY"]; 
            }
            }
           
                if($sr2 == 1){
                $t_Qty += $row["QUANTITY"]; 
            }
            
       ?>
               <tr  style="
<?php if($sr == 3){ ?>
    border-bottom: 3px solid lightblue;
        <?php } ?>       ">
                <?php if($g_contract != $prev_contract) { 
                     
                    ?>
                 <td style="font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row["CONTRACT#"] ?? '' ; ?>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="web_y_n"  style="text-align: right;vertical-align: middle;margin-top: -2px;" 
                     class="web_y_n" id="web_y_n" contract_no="<?php echo $row["CONTRACT#"] ;

                      ?>"
                      <?php 
                          $web_y_n = $row["WEB_Y_N"] ?? ''; 
                       if($web_y_n == "YES"){ ?>
                            checked
                       <?php }else{

                       } ?> 
                     >
                 </td>
                 <td style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $row["CONTRACTDATE"] ?? '' ; ?></td>
                  <td style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $row["SALEMANNAME"] ?? ''; ?></td>
                   <td style="font-weight: bold;max-width: 200px;"><?php echo $row["CUSTOMERNAME"] ?? '' ; ?></td>
               <?php 
              $prev_contract = $g_contract;
             

                }else{
                    echo "<td colspan='4'></td>";
    

                } 
                
                    $ship_date = $row["SHIP_DATE"] ?? '';
              
             $g_shipdate = $g_contract.$ship_date;
         
                if($g_shipdate != $prev_shipdate) { ?>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $row["SHIP_DATE"] ?? '' ; ?></td>

  <?php 
  $prev_shipdate = $g_shipdate;
   }else{
    echo "<td></td>";
  } 

  ?>
        <td><?php echo $row["DESCRIPTION"] ?? ''; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["WEAVENAME"] ?? ''; ?></td>
         <?php   ?>
          <td><?php 
          
          if($sr  == 2){
            echo "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>SubTotal</span>";
          }elseif ($sr == 3) {
            echo "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>Contract Total</span>";
          }else{
          echo $row["LOOMABRV"] ?? ''; 
      }?></td>
          
         <td style= "text-align: right;
               <?php  if($sr  == 2 || $sr==3 ){ ?>
             font-weight: bold;
               <?php } ?>
         "><?php echo isset($row["SHIP_MTR"]) ? number_format($row["SHIP_MTR"]) : '' ; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["MAINPRODUCTNAME"] ?? '';?></td>
          <td style="text-align: right;border-right: 3px solid lightblue;
            <?php  if($sr  == 2 || $sr==3 ){ ?>
             font-weight: bold;
               <?php } ?>
          "><?php echo isset($row["SHIP_QTY"]) ? number_format($row["SHIP_QTY"]) : ''; ?></td>
            

 
      <?php  
     

 $q_reqDate = $row["REQDATE"] ?? '';

      if($q_reqDate != $prev_reqDate) { 

        ?>
        
    <td style="font-weight:bold;text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["REQDATE"] ?? ''; ?></td>

<?php
 
$prev_reqDate = $q_reqDate;

}else{
    echo "<td></td>";
    
} 

?>
    <td><?php echo $row["DESCRIPTION2"] ?? '';  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["WEAVENAME2"] ?? '';  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["LOOMABRV2"] ?? '';  ?></td>
    <td><?php 
    if(empty($row["DEMAND#"]) && (!empty($row["QUANTITY"]))){
        if($sr2 == 2){
        echo "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>SubTotal</span>";
    }
     if($sr2 == 3){
        echo "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>Contract Total</span>";
     }
    }else{
    echo $row["DEMAND#"] ?? '';
    }  ?></td>
     <td style="text-align:right;
<?php if(empty($row["DEMAND#"]) && (!empty($row["QUANTITY"]))){ ?>
    font-weight: bold;
    <?php } ?>
     "><?php echo 
isset($row["QUANTITY"]) ? number_format($row["QUANTITY"]) : ''; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php  } ?>
     <tr style="font-weight:bold;text-align: right;">
        <td colspan="8" style="padding-right: 10px;">Grand Total</td>
         <td ><?php echo number_format($t_shipMtr); ?></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><?php echo number_format($t_shipQty); ?></td>
         <td colspan="5"></td>
         <td><?php echo number_format($t_Qty); ?></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[Here Is Screen shoot given .From 2nd Date or bold border in midle start 2nd Query it is not parallel to left reult.Please guide me how i display record right side record parallel or front to  left ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YWES.jpg

Comment: Please, please use _bind_ variables in your SQL statements instead of string concatenation like `BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'`.  Bind variables are important for security and scalability.  See the examples in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php and also in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/underground-php-oracle-manual.html).

Comment: If you simplify your question, someone may be able to answer it.